# Selenium Webdriver: How do I grab by class name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, getattribute

GOAL: Print "Eden Ivy" onto my console.

I am following [the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name) for Selenium Webdriver.

The following is the line of interest. Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot.]

HTML:

`<a href="/model/77291/eden-ivy" title="Eden Ivy" class="sc-1b6bgon-7 cGUerq">Eden Ivy</a>`

How exactly do I grab and print "Eden Ivy" ?

I tried:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sc-1b6bgon')
print(name)
```

and

```
name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sc-1b6bgon-7 cGUerq')
print(name)
```

But they don't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I can't use the words "Eden Ivy" when grabbing, it has to be by element. So that I can use this function for other names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be difficult to extract the *innerHTML* using the class attributes as they are dynamic in nature.

To print the `innerText` ***Eden Ivy*** attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()]//following::div[1]/span/a").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()]//following::div[1]/span/a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks but it cannot be specific to this name. In other words, the "grabbing" cannot include the words "Eden Ivy" so I can use this for other names as well. Should have probably mentioned that.

Comment: Chckout the answer update and let me if any further questions.

Comment: Fam thank you for answering. What's throwing me off is you have "a[title='Eden Ivy']" I'm trying to avoid using the words "Eden Ivy" so that I can use the same function for other names. I'm not sure if I'm explaining correctly. For instance, I copy paste the same function in a different page and print "Michael Scott"

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Fam the XPATH has "'Budap-Assed" which is specific to this page. I don't think I'm explaining correctly. What I want is this: You use the function in the page above, it prints "Eden Ivy". You use the same function in a different page within the same website, it prints "Michael Scott". Is this not possible? Sorry I'm dumb.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.